# Правописание местоимения 2 л. мн.ч. в Интернете / Correct spelling of 2nd pl. pronoun on the Internet

Tags: правописание, узус

Правильно ли написание "Вы" со строчной буквы в Интернете? Является ли подобное написание трендом?

Is it correct to spell Вы (you 2nd.p. pl.) with lower case letter on the Internet? Is it a trend?

Answer (score 4):

This specific question has been [formally answered by the Russian Language Institute](http://web.archive.org/web/20081022205917/http://www.yandex.ru/info/you_full.html) in July of 2000. The recommendation is not to capitalize "вы" when writing for the Internet.

> Вы, Ваш пишутся с прописной буквы при обращении к одному лицу в текстах следующих жанров:
>
> - (а) личное письмо (адресат - конкретное лицо; факультативное написание - выбор определяет сам пишущий, выражая/ не выражая вежливое или уважительное отношение к адресату);
> - (б) официальные документы (адресат - конкретное лицо, отношение пишущего к адресату не имеет значения);
> - (в) анкеты (адресат - неконкретное лицо; отношение пишущего к адресату не имеет значения).
>
> Поскольку большинство текстов Интернета не соответствуют условиям (а), (б), (в) написания Вы с прописной буквы (сообщения электронной почты не являются личными письмами в традиционном смысле слова), можно рекомендовать написание вы, ваш при обращении к читателям/ посетителям страницы в Интернете со строчной буквы.
>
> "Вы" is capitalized in texts of these three genres:
>
> - (а) Personal letters (addressed to a specific person; this is optional - the decision is up to the writer, who wishes or does not wish to express additional respect to the addressee)
> - (б) Official documents (addressed to a specific person, regardless of whether or not the writer would like to express additional respect to the addressee)
> - (в) Official forms (not addressed to anyone in particular, regardless of whether or not the writer would like to express additional respect to the addressee)
>
> Since the majority of Internet texts do not meet the conditions (а), (б), (в) for capitalizing of "Вы" (e-mails are not personal correspondence in the traditional meaning of the word), we recommend writing "вы", "ваш" without capitalizing the first letter when referring to readers / visitors of your site.

Comment: E-mail exactly **is** "personal letter" in our 21st century.

Comment: @farfareast Although I agree with you on that e-mail has taken the place of the personal mail of the past, it looks like our positions are in disagreement with the opinion of the Russian Language Institute. I used to capitalize "Вы" in all my Internet communications before reading the above opinion. After that, I switched to lowercase "вы" in my forum posts, but kept it capitalized in my e-mails.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight +1 [Письмо Д. Э. Розенталя читателю относительно правописания местоимения вы](http://www.artlebedev.ru/kovodstvo/sections/165/)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: in fact my opinion is very close to yours and in some disagreement with the Manjusri in OP.  There was some trend of overusing Вы before by placing it practically everywhere. Now it comes back to normal. It is not about internet. Russian language rules never required writing Вы always from capital letter when it addresses a single person. +1 for the letter of Russian  language institute.

Comment: It would seem to me, the three listed cases enumerate, when capitalizing is _mandatory_. It is still _appropriate_ in on all other contexts, when the author is politely referring to a single person.

Answer (score 2):

When you are referring to an individual person to whom you are being polite or expressing respect, you should use an uppercase *В* regardless where you use it: in a book, in a letter, in an internet post, etc.

The reason you're seeing it often written in internet post starting with the lowercase *в* is quite simple: speed.  People tend to shorten words and make shortcuts in order to express their thoughts quicker.  It is (for some unknown to me reason) assumed that on the internet one should write as little as possible - using shorthand, abbreviations, etc. - just to get the thought is put across. This in turns translates into the desire to use as few as possible keystrokes. Writing *Вы* starting with a capital letter would mean to press **[Shift]** button one more time, which means more time taken to complete the post.  Hence a lot of people don't do it.

The other simple reason is that many people simple disregard the fact that you should use capital *В* in this scenario and use lowercase letter everywhere, including hand-written texts.

So, to answer your question, it is not *correct* spelling, but it is a spelling that just came to be.  People accept it, just as people accept others making other grammatical mistakes. As for it being a trend, I wouldn't say that it's a trend in itself, it's part of the trend to shorten everything, including the number of key presses.

Comment: В школе эти люди плохо учились (или до сих пор там плохо учатся или вообще редко её посещают) - вот главная причина. Очень сомневаюсь, что все руководствуются рекомендациями Института русского языка, о которых написал dasblinkenlight. Если вообще знают про этот институт.

Comment: @КуЪ Я вроде неплохо учился :-), но это правило (писать Вы с большой буквы) было как бы неформальным, не помню, чтобы его преподавали в школе. Опять же написание Вы с большой буквы означало очень большой пиетет по отношению к человеку. Сейчас, в эпоху интернета, похоже, считается приличным писать Вы при обращении к любому незнакомому человеку.

Comment: Из Справочника издателя и автора Аркадия Эммануиловича Мильчина ясно, что местоимение "вы" с заглавной буквы на сайте (неличное обращение) - ошибка. У Артемия Лебедева есть по этому поводу заметка со сканом письма Розенталя - http://www.artlebedev.ru/kovodstvo/sections/165/

Comment: @CleverMasha Пожалуйста, приведите пример неличного обращения с использованием _вы_. Где бы не был написан текст, если _Вы_ используется при обращении к одному человеку, а не к группе, то это как раз и есть **личное** обращение.

Comment: @AleksG: I think what CleverMasha means is that sometimes "you" can be used as placeholder similar to "one" or "a person". F.e. Когда вы приезжаете на море, вам первым делом надо сделать то-то и то-то. Let's call this usage _abstract_. I think, definitely, in abstract usage of вы it should be written from small letter. The real question is: Should we *always* write Вы from capital in "concrete" usage (when we mean exactly the person whom we address)?

Comment: @farfareast Oh, I see.  I believe the "abstract" usage would not qualify as addressing _an individual_.  It's closer to addressing a group of people than an individual.