# Что означает слово "дятька"?

Tags: значения, сленг

Я наткнулся на него читая комменты под видео обзором игры.

> ВОПРОС: **Дятька** а вы нуб?﻿
>
> ОТВЕТ: ваще полнейший)))))﻿

Answer (score 10):

Хочу добавить к ответу Shady_arc что "дядька" или "дядя" имеет оттенок "взрослый мужчина" и даже "мужчина старше (говорящего)" (как "дед" или "дедушка" означает "старый мужчина" или "мужчина гораздо старше меня")

Это также подкрепляется местоимением "вы", которое в неформальном общении используется для обращения к более старшим (по возрасту или статусу) людям - люди одного возраста обычно используют "ты".

То есть скрытый смысл вопроса "Ты такой большой, а играть толком не умеешь, да?".

---

I want to add to Shady_arc's answer that "дядька" can also have a flavour of "mature man" or even "a little bit older than me" (like "дед" is "old man", at least much older than the speaker).

This is also backed by using the "вы" pronoun that is mostly used to elder (or having the higher social status) persons in informal speech (when the persons are of the same age they would likely use "ты" instead).

So, the "real" meaning of the "Дятька а вы нуб?﻿" is "You are so mature, but play like a baby, isn't it?".

Comment: Следует учитывать, потерявшее своё значение на форумах и в чатах правило: "Вы" - при обращении к одному человеку, "вы" - к двум или нескольким. Ну, это если строго следовать грамматике.

Comment: @IvanBlack В этом правиле есть тонкости - вот [отдельное обсуждение](http://russian.stackexchange.com/q/1802/551).

Comment: весьма расплывчатое правило (а точнее умозаключение после правила) - я например трактую его так (см. мой комент выше), и судя по всему можно спорить бесконечно по этому поводу. Спасибо за ссылку.

Answer (score 5):

"Дятька" is a misspelling (perhaps, *deliberate*) of "дядька".

Comment: @Artemix this actually provides an answer to the question, though it short, but this happens. Comments usually  does not provide answer to the question.

Comment: BTW/кстати, есть такой город - Дятьково: "Дя́тьково — город в России, административный центр Дятьковского района Брянской области"

Answer (score 4):

- То же, что `дядя` ; брат отца или матери, а также муж тёти (т. е. сестры отца или матери) по отношению к своим племянникам

> Но потом приехал мой дядька, брат отца.

- Любой взрослый мужчина

> Какой-то дядька сидел на стуле с гармонью в руках.

Answer (score 0):

Actually "Дядька" (дядя) which is sometimes used coloquialy for "man", "fellow", "dude".